# Error: JQuery y AJAX

Tags: java, jquery

Estoy trabajando con jquery y servlet en java y al intentar hacer la conexión a un método me manda el siguiente error.

> http://localhost:8080/AtnMedicaWeb/atencion/prueba: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not
>   equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Este es mi método para conectar:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/AtnMedicaWeb/atencion/prueba",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:8080'},
        success: function(response){
        },
        failure: function(){
            //location.href = "index.html";
        }
    });
```

Comment: En la url a  que accedes por ajax, ¿coincide el nombre del host con el que se ve en la barra de navegación del browser? Sospecho que la página que hace uso de ese ajax no ha sido obtenida de una petición a localhost, sino tal vez directamente del sistema de archivos (`file://`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque por seguridad los servidores bloquean la invocación de procesos desde clientes que no pertenecen al mismo dominio. Esto se soluciona dando permiso a un dominio en particular o bien o a cualquier dominio.

La configuración la puedes hacer desde el servidor o desde tu servlet, si lo haces desde tu servlet, aquí te dejo un ejemplo: https://amodernstory.com/2014/12/27/using-cors-headers-with-java-example/

Si usas Tomcat como servidor, aquí hay un ejemplo de configuración:
https://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer el servidor no está permitiendo el conexión, podrías realizar la configuración de tu archivo .htaccess para que permita la conexión.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```